# ConnectThread error during memcpy

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, memcpy

I am using 2 character arrays (one of them is declared static)

```
static char st_arr[8192];
char arr[162];
int itr = 0;
```

arr is being instantiated in a method foo() where it gets filled with 162 (or less) bytes of data. This data is being copied to st_arr using memcpy()

```
void foo() {
   for(int i=0; i<some_len; i++) { //some_len < 162
       arr[i] = some_obj->data[i];
   }
   memcpy(&st_arr[itr], arr, some_len);
   itr += some_len;
}
```

Here foo() gets called recursively and the aim is to fill st_arr with the complete data we get from arr in each foo() call.

This works but I often get the following:

```
beginThreadex Connect Thread error [%d][%s]
```

at the end of st_arr.
What could be the reason of this error.
I am clearing st_arr at the end of my procedure using memcpy:

```
memcpy(&st_arr[0], "", sizeof(st_arr));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcpy(&st_arr[0], "", sizeof(st_arr));` is undefined behavior.

You are trying to copy `sizeof(st_arr)` bytes (8192 based on your example) of memory from `""`, where only 1 byte is available, since empty string consists only of null terminator (`'\0'`), so you are reading past the end of memory allocated for such an empty string.

To zero-out the memory, consider using [`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset):

```
std::memset (&st_arr[0], 0, sizeof(st_arr));
```

Comment: Problem solved!
Thanks Algirdas for the answer! Cheers